# What are the possible errors in std::stringstream (ways to set failbit and badbit)?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

What are the possible errors in `std::stringstream`?

Specifically, `std::stringstream` derives off of `std::ios`, which means that it has an `std::ios::rdstate`. In `std::ios::rdstate`, we have a problem when either `failbit` or `badbit` are set. As such, what are the possible ways to set the `failbit` and `badbit` in `std::stringstream`?

Are the ways to set `failbit` and `badbit` compiler/implementation dependent or are they specified by the standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table 124 in C++11 specifies what the individual bits *mean:*

> **badbit** indicates a loss of integrity in an input or output sequence (such as an
>   irrecoverable read error from a file);
>
> **eofbit** indicates that an input operation reached the end of an input sequence;
>
> **failbit** indicates that an input operation failed to read the expected characters, or
>   that an output operation failed to generate the desired characters.

As to what operations *set* those bits, that's scattered around the standard in various places, you can just search for occurrences of the mask to find out what sets and clears it.

For *example,* one way the `badbit` can be set is if you use the get an exception during an `operator>>` call to an `istream`. This is detailed in `27.7.2.2 Formatted input functions`. There are many other places throughout the standard which give similar descriptions.